# Prevent Windows 8 Sleep music

Tags: windows-8, sleep

Nine times out of ten when my computer goes to sleep, Windows 8 will start to play music (some kind of guitar strumming) ... How can I stop this?!

The closest I've found to an answer is [this from Microsofts website](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-i-get-windows-8-to-stop-playing-music-when/a5a14cb8-e85a-4d3b-bb6a-e6d27e43c664) which basically tells me to solve it I need to unplug my peripherals which really sounds like an idiotic solution if it were to work, and not something I could do every time.

Comment: could you please explain what kind of music ? Is it just bleeping ?

Comment: Huh? What music? Is it music from your music collection or random tunes? Do you mean _sleep_ or that the screensaver is turned on?

Comment: Its been described in that link as a "Guitar strumming" which sounds very accurate, I've not managed to find the sound file in power or audio settings anywhere

Comment: Wow, really weird. Could you check if removing the peripherals solves it? I agree that is not a solution but it might be a clue.

Comment: @terdon - Sure, I'll give it a try but not got high hopes for it as you may expect, not sure how long it will take me to figure out if it worked though lol

Comment: Is this sound playing just during the time Windows is preparing to go to sleep or is it playing all the time. Because if it is playing all the time that means that Windows did not go to sleep. Check your options for sleeping or hibernation

Comment: @terdon - Tried it and no luck, ever heard of a sleep music setting somewhere ? :S

Comment: @Devid - It is directly after my screen goes black as it prepares to go into sleep, never gave it long enough to find out where it goes to because it always makes me jump (somewimes wake up myself) and whack my keyboard to bring it back to normal

Comment: Just realised that its a screensaver sound, (got the sleep mode idea in my head from that link), any tips on stopping screensaver music?

Comment: @Sayse sorry, no, no idea. I have never used Windows8 and the last time I used Windows as my main OS, I was using win98 so... I assume you've checked the options for the screensaver you are using?Maybe change screensavers?

Comment: @terdon - thats exactly what I did, I didn't even realise I had a screensaver as my screen goes blank instead of showing any screensaver anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound like a sleep issue, because windows is inactive during sleep. Go to your control panel and select personalization, check the sound options i think that is where the problem is.

[image: control panel, personalisation]

Comment: You were partially correct and it was your comments that made me realise, the actual issue was Acer's default screensaver plays this idiotic music. Many thanks!

Comment: yes actually it is not the sound option as i show above in the picture, but the screensaver options you can also see in my picture above. It is left from the sounds. There in the options lies the solution to your problem, or just turn off the screensaver